# Is the van der Waals fluid viscous?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, gas, viscosity

The van der Waals equation of states is well known:
$$\tag{1}
p(\rho) = \frac{a \rho}{1 - b \rho} - c\rho^2.
$$
What is the energy-momentum tensor of this gas, considered as a fluid?  Is it the simple "perfect fluid" expression, i.e:
$$\tag{2}
T_{ab} = (\rho + p) \, u_a \, u_b - p \, \eta_{ab} \; ?
$$
If so, then the van der Waals fluid doesn't have any shear viscosity and doesn't conduct heath (but it may have "bulk viscosity", with pressure $p \Rightarrow p(\rho) - \zeta \Theta$ where $\Theta$ is the expansion scalar).

Does the van der Waals fluid have shear and bulk viscosity?  Then what is its energy-momentum tensor?

And how can we find that the fluid has viscosity from its equation of states (1) alone ?

Comment: The vdw fluid definitely has viscosity.  I don’t know what its energy momentum tensor looks like, however.

Comment: @ChetMiller, does that fluid has both a shear viscosity $\eta$ and a bulk viscosity $\zeta$?  If it has only bulk viscosity (i.e if $\eta = 0$), then its energy-momentum tensor should be (2) above.

Comment: It would have shear viscosity as well (as would a real gas in the ideal gas limit).

Comment: @ChetMiller, the *ideal gas* doesn't have any viscosity.  A real gas is not an "ideal gas".

Comment: Then how do they have negligible temperature change in the Joule-Thomson experiment?  If they are not viscous, they should cool.  Ideal gases have mean free paths and display collisions between molecules, and this is the very effect that gives rise to viscosity.  In the limit of low pressure corresponding to ideal gas behavior, real gases exhibit viscosity.  Viscosity is the mechanistic cause of negligible temperature change in Joule-Thomson of ideal gases.

Comment: @ChetMiller, an *ideal gas* is described by the equation of state $p V = N k T$, and is a special case of a perfect fluid, with energy-momentum (2), and it doesn't have any of the two viscosity coefficients $\eta$ and $\zeta$ (bulk viscosity).  An ideal gas is just an approximation of real gas, which do have viscosities (except Helium superfluids).

Comment: Well, in chem engineering, we consider ideal gasses to have viscosity.

Comment: Also, note that the equation of state you wrote pV = NkT applies only at thermodynamic equilibrium, and viscosity is a non-equilibrium (transport) effect.

Comment: @ChetMiller, so you imply that *perfect fluids* could have a viscosity while having the same energy-momentum tensor as (2)?

Comment: I am not familiar with the expression of the energy momentum tensor for non-equilibrium situations because of my limited background in relativity.  However, I do know that, in classical fluid dynamics, the 3D stress tensor for a viscous compressible Newtonian fluid has an isotropic stress term that depends on viscosity (and not just equilibrium pressure), and a deviatoric stress term with a proportionality factor of viscosity.